# How to remove trailing zeroes from datediff results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, datetime

I have a startDateTime and endDateTime. I am trying to find the total difference between them in hours.
I use DATEDIFF() to get the difference in hours, (but in minute format, so ten hours 30 min would be 630 min). I divided by 60 to get the total remainder (since using days was rounding to 1 based on boundary rules)

Start date looks like 2020-12-03 10:00:00.000, same with end date in terms of formatting

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,startDateTime,endDateTime) / 60.0 AS [CalculatedDate]
FROM [dbo].[ATable]
```

Produces

```
CalculatedDate
-------------
10.50000
9.500000
7.500000
```

Trying to figure out how to remove the trailing zeroes to just 10.5, 9.5 etc.

Tried round, cast, and some other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want `format()`?

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(
        DATEDIFF(minute,startDateTime,endDateTime) / 60.0,
        '#.#####'
    ) AS [CalculatedDate]
FROM [dbo].[ATable]
```

This allows up to 5 decimal digits. Only significant digits are displayed (so typically, `10.50000` is displayed as `10.5`). If there are more than 5 significant decimal digits, the value is rounded to the closest 5th decimal.

I should pinpoint that this returns a *string* datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to the fixed-length format that you want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), DATEDIFF(minute, startDateTime, endDateTime) / 60.0) AS [CalculatedDate]
FROM [dbo].[ATable]
```

Comment: error message, are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), DATEDIFF(minute,startDateTime,endDateTime) / 60.0) AS [CalculatedDate] <--That works, just left out a parenthesis. Thanks for your time